# DIY motor project - Help needed for configuring Maytech 6374 motor

Tags: batteries, current, circuit-design

I have very elementary electrical knowledge.  I need help with configuring motors.  I have dual Maytech 6374 motors (150 kV, 08 A idle current, 65 A max current, 60 A rated current, max output 3550 W, max input 50 V).

I have dual Maytech 100 A, V6 VESC (cont 100 A, burst 240 A, max input 50 V). I am trying to figure out optimal dual battery setup.  These will be used like trolling motors for a small boat and will need longer run times to last a day of fishing, but I don't want to sacrifice power.

I have a 48 V, 1276 Wh, 25 A lithium battery with max discharge of 40 A to hook to each motor, but even with two of them, that seems like it will underpower the motors.  Thoughts?

Should I use an inline antispark device, an inline on/off switch, a 60 A inline fuse to prevent over-discharge from the battery and burning out my electronics?  How would the electrical gurus configure a system?

Comment: 40A battery for 60A motor you cannot expect full motor power. Does the battery have an overcurrent protection? Is it activated during run?

Comment: I realize that a max 40a battery for a max 60a motor will under perform.  It was more a question of is there a better solution?  Trying not to fry my VESC or motors.  In the 48v battery there is, but if I were to put some dumb lithium batteries in series, there would not be.

Comment: A migration to drone stack might be in order: https://drones.stackexchange.com/